# Tidy equivalent of Ruby #map and #join for C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, map-function

I've got the following simple example from a recent C# project:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection toNodes = node.SelectNodes(@".//div[@class='email-to']//span");
string toString = "";
foreach(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode toNode in toNodes)
{
  toString += toNode.Attributes["title"].Value + ", ";
}
toString = toString.Substring(0, toString.Length - 2);
```

If I was doing the same in Ruby, I'd do:

```
to_string = node.select_nodes(".//div[@class='email-to']//span").map{ |to_node|
  to_node.attributes["title"].value
}.join(', ')
```

I've found myself wanting for a `map` equivalent a few times in C# but haven't yet found something suitable. I've found the [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation and whilst it looks like what I might want, I couldn't work out how to apply that to the above example.

I've also seen examples around of using LINQ and haven't been able to get my head around how to translate other examples to something like the above.

Is there a tidier way of achieving the same result in C# in comparison to what I've done, and how is best to achieve that? One of my big concerns is readability and maintainability so I don't want something which will cause the code to be unnecessarily obfuscated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like LINQ [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you're looking for :

```
var result = String.Join(", ", 
                node.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='email-to']//span")
                    .Select(o => o.GetAttributeValue("title",""))
            );
```